# Jfrog Artifactory tries to list docker tags from remote repos too

Tags: artifactory

I see ton of logs from jfrog artifactory for listing docker tags. It tries to list my local docker registry images from remote repos too. Is there any way to disable that? If it finds the tags from local repo, not to seek from remote repos?

```
2019-10-09 15:43:40,319 [http-nio-8081-exec-70] [INFO ] (o.a.a.d.r.v.DockerV2RemoteRepoHandler:266) - Fetching docker tags for 'company/someapp-app' in repo 'bintray-docker-remote'

2019-10-09 15:43:40,504 [http-nio-8081-exec-70] [ERROR] (o.a.a.d.r.v.DockerV2RemoteRepoHandler:283) - Unable to fetch tags from 'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/company/someapp-app/tags/list?': HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
2019-10-09 15:43:40,463 [http-nio-8081-exec-70] [ERROR] (o.a.a.d.r.v.DockerV2RemoteRepoHandler:283) - Unable to fetch tags from 'https://docker.bintray.io/v2/company/someapp-app/tags/list?': HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: Ugh.... I'm being hit with this, too.
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-21995?jql=text%20~%20%22.DockerV2RemoteRepoHandler%20Unable%20to%20fetch%20tags%22